# python write may parameters to file

Tags: fwrite

I have lots of parametrs which I have to add between text: e.g. I would like to write:
Anne has 3 apples.
with

name="Anne"

numFruit=3

fruit="apples"

with print I could do the following:

```
print '{myName} has {myNumFruit} {myFruit}.'.format(
...       myName=name, myNumFruit=numFruit, myFruit=fruit)
```

In this it does not matter in which order I give the variables.
Is there somethins similar for write (write to file), or do I have to do it via %s, %d, etc and keep track of the order in which I call the variables in the text?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're wanting to do.  Writing to a file is just a string, and "somestring".format() is also a string.  Are you just wanting to write the resulting string to the file?

Comment: Why are you not using a dictionary ?

Comment: Ahhh... sorry for the stupid quesiton: You just answered it! .format is a string function! So I can now do s=... (instead of print(...)) and do write(s)!

Comment: What would a dictionary help?